# Pi Zero 2 W Ad Hoc Range

Tags: networking, wifi-direct, pi-zero-w-2, zero-configuration-networking

I would like to know Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W's transmission range for ad-hoc transmission.

Currently, I'm planning a communication network between Pis. I am talking about multi-hop communication.
I can't find any information about the Raspberry antenna.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: the range is dependent on the environment ... please run some tests

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.